# Keyboard Navigation - Using the tab key to navigate through controls

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have searched through stack overflow, however, I couldn't find any solution. I believe the issue is coming from customized controls or I'm doing something wrong. I'm using a customized TabControl called "Dragablz" and whenever I try to navigate using the 'Tab' key on the keyboard, it seems to go on TabItems, TabControl background, etc. I wanted to achieve to navigate only through controls inside the Grid of the current selected TabItem (Buttons, Comboboxes, etc).

Here is the code

```
<Tool:DialogHost x:Name="RDialog" Loaded="OnRootDialog_Loaded" Identifier="RootDialog">
    <Dock:Layout>
        <Dbz:TabablzControl x:Name="TabControl" TextElement.Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=Background}">
            <TabItem Header="DEVICE" x:Name="tabItemDevice">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDevice" Width="300" FontSize="15" Tool:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Select Device:" SelectionChanged="OnDeviceComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbAddress" Width="150" FontSize="15" Margin="30" Tool:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Select Address:" SelectionChanged="OnDeviceComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Button x:Name="btnStartStop" Content="_START" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 -4 -5" Click="OnDeviceButton_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnConfigureDevice" Content="_CONFIGURE DEVICE" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-3 0 0 -5" Click="OnDeviceButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="PHONEBOOK" x:Name="tabItemPhonebook">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="-6" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button TabIndex="2" x:Name="btnNewClient" Content="_NEW CLIENT" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="OnPhonebookButton_Click"/>
                        <Button TabIndex="1" Margin="10 0 0 0" x:Name="btnOpenPhonebook" Content="_OPEN PHONEBOOK" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="OnPhonebookButton_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="MANAGE CALLS" x:Name="tabItemManageCall">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="-6" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button TabIndex="3" x:Name="btnCallRecord" Content="_CALL RECORDS" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="OnManageCallsButton_Click"/>
                        <Button TabIndex="4" x:Name="btnDial" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="_DIAL" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="OnManageCallsButton_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="SETTINGS" x:Name="tabItemSetting">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="-6" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="btnApplicationSetting" Content="APPLICATION SETTINGS"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnContactMe" Content="CONTACT ME" Margin="10 0 0 0" Click="OnSettingsButton_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </Dbz:TabablzControl>
    </Dock:Layout>
</Tool:DialogHost>
```

I've tried using the following; `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"`

Unfortunately, it didn't work, it still goes through the tab items, I only want to navigate inside the TabItem Controls.

Thank you!

Workaround I managed to make;

```
private void OnMainWindow_KeyDown(object Sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            if (TabControl.SelectedIndex == 0) /* Device */
            {
                if(!cmbDevice.IsFocused || !cmbAddress.IsFocused
                    || btnConfigureDevice.IsFocused || btnStartStop.IsFocused)
                {
                    cmbDevice.Focus();
                }
                else if (cmbDevice.IsFocused)
                {
                    cmbAddress.Focus();
                }
                else if (cmbAddress.IsFocused)
                {
                    btnConfigureDevice.Focus();
                }
                else if (btnConfigureDevice.IsFocused)
                {
                    btnStartStop.Focus();
                }
                else if (btnStartStop.IsFocused)
                {
                    cmbDevice.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it doesn't enter any children of a tab into tab order? What about with TabIndex=0 on the first control of an item or using control.focus on selection of an item? Since it's third party did you check their source in their git?

Comment: Hi Chris, it does enter in the children of the tabs, but it takes a few tabs unfortunately. I'll see what I can find, thanks.

Comment: If that's all it's doing, and you're not sure which parts are stealing those ghost stab stops you could use XAML Spy to catch what's receiving those additional unwanted tabs and set them to IsTabStop=False so they don't receive tab anymore. Sounds like then you'd have your desired behavior.

Comment: Using IsTabStop on TabItems will stop tab from going inside the child(s) of that particular TabItem.

Comment: Not the TabItem, but sometimes there's nested controls inside a control template or a UserControl or something somewhere that will act as an unwanted tab stop.